# Bash script not recognizing file

Tags: bash, shell

I am attempting to write a bash script. In a test, I wrote a script to check for the existence of `test.txt`. However, no matter how many times I try to change the formatting, the code still does not recognize the file.

```
    while [ "$INPUT" != "quit" ]; do
        read INPUT
        COMMANDFILE=test.txt
        if [ -f $COMMANDFILE ]; then
            echo "Found file!"
        fi
    done
```

I am 100% positive `text.txt` exists and is in the same folder as my script.

Comment: Are you sure `test.txt` actually exists?

Comment: And don't just answer "yes" or "no" to the question above; show us the command you have used to verify the file existence.

Comment: You should read the input *after* you print the message.

Comment: Your code works for me (and, as Barmar points out, prints "Found file!" again after I enter "quit").

Comment: Make sure you have right file permissions, that the file is indeed in the same folder and try to debug your script with some more commands (E.G. `readlink -f "${COMMANDFILE}"`) or launching your script with `set -x ./script`

Comment: What ist your current directory when you start your script and in which directory is your file test.txt?

Comment: As an aside, all-caps names are used for variables meaningful to the shell itself; it's good practice to use names with at least one character for your own variables, to avoid changing the shell's behavior unintentionally. We have lots of questions here asking why nothing works after they ran a loop `for PATH in */; do`! -- see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html for the POSIX spec setting out all-caps namespace as reserved (or, rather, setting out the *contrary* namespace as reserved for application use).

Comment: "In the same folder as my script" is not the folder that counts. The **current directory when your script is running** is the directory from which the script was started, not the directory the script is in.

Comment: What did you type as input to the script?

Comment: The `-f` test is for checking that the file exists *and* it is a *regular file* - so it is possible that `test.txt` exists but is something other than a regular file, such as a named pipe or even a directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this case I would add some debug lines to my script to make sure my thinking is correct. For instance:

```
while [ "$INPUT" != "quit" ]; do
    read INPUT
    COMMANDFILE=test.txt
    echo "debug: now I'm in $( pwd ) directory. dir listing:"
    ls -la
    if [ -f $COMMANDFILE ]; then
        echo "Found file!"
    fi
done
```

also, please note that linux filenames are case sensitive (meaning you can have test.txt and TeSt.txt in the same directory). So, for instance if you have the file named TEST.TXT, [ -f test.txt ] will evaluate to false (unless test.txt exists as well)

Comment: `"$PWD"` is much more efficient to run than `$(pwd)` (which spawns off a subshell, fork()ing off a whole new process just to check the directory in it).

Comment: Also, the `[ -f $COMMANDFILE ]` test is itself faulty due to the lack of quotes; if the current value of `IFS` contains a `.`, for example, it'll parse as `[ -f "test" "txt" ]`, which is false.